# Detect size in kilobytes of aCanvas.toDataURI

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

Is it possible to measure/detect the size of an image that I generated from `canvas.toDataURI` method?

I need to detect if its greater then a certain size, and if it is then tell user its too big for upload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this?
http://jsfiddle.net/qb65r4Lf/

```
//pass string into the function...
function byteCount(s) {
    return encodeURI(s).split(/%..|./).length - 1;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @Barrie! I will test this out and report back. I'll test by saving a canvas to file and seeing size, and then also taking it toDataURL and seeing size with this. :)

Comment: This site allows you to upload an image and see the size differences http://dataurl.net/#dataurlmaker

Comment: Thanks Ill test that site, but in my png test it wasnt the same as file size on OS :( Image is here: http://i.imgur.com/Ht3RXyK.png and the data uri is here: http://jsfiddle.net/qb65r4Lf/2/  js method is saying 750, but OS is saying 544 bytes EDIT: Ah that website report the same! Interesting! Is it possible to get file size that it will be on os from javasscript?

Comment: I guess it's an inherent difference between "physical" files and DataUrls. Perhaps just store the dataurls instead of the binary pngs? edit: at least it will be consistent!

Comment: The only way you can get a file size is to save the file temporarily (using PHP or the like) then "read" the data back before permanently saving it.